# Error in using INTEROP does not exist in the namespace in Blazor application Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, blazor

I am creating an application to study Blazor.
I created a Razor View following a tutorial and in this view the following using the

```
@using TesteBlazor.Shared
@using TesteBlazor.Shared.Models
@page "/ clients"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Interop
@inject HttpClient Http
```

**But the problem is that my visual studio complains that Interop does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser'**

How do I get Interop to work on my application?
Do I have to import any library?

Since I'm starting, I'm not sure what to do.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser' (are you missing an assembly reference?) TesteBlazor.Client`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `@using Microsoft.JSInterop`

Also:  @page "/clients"

Comment: Issac made the changes as you posted.

The error no longer occurs.

BUT when I am going to include a new registration the entire screen gives loading ... being that the only correct table is loading loading ...

This happens in Add Client and Edit Client

No Delete Client works perfectly.

Comment: @Cyberlacs, please mark the current question as answered. Then post a new question, detailing the problem accompanied with the code you're using... thanks

Comment: See my question on another question as per request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064493/problems-with-using-microsoft-jsinterop-in-blazor-applications